# Hourly Total Average of a Group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find the combined hourly average (travel time in this case) from a group of segments (code in the below)
I get can get each segment individually but want to return sum all segments to produce one average for the group.   My results give the average of all of the segments instead of the average combined time for all of the segments

[image: Desired and Getting]

```
SELECT
    (DATEPART(YEAR, RT1.[Segment_Date])) AS "YEAR",
    (DATEPART(MONTH, RT1.[Segment_Date])) AS "MONTH",
    (DATEPART(DD, RT1.[Segment_Date])) AS "DAY",
    (DATEPART(HH, RT1.[Segment_Date])) AS "HOUR",
    AVG(
        CASE WHEN Code IN (
            '149242059',
            '393397506',
            '393507671',
            '429235061',
            '429235101',
            '429235108',
            '429235159',
            '429235160',
            '429235161',
            '429255654',
            '429255655'
        ) THEN ([TravelTimeMinutes]) ELSE 0 END
    ) AS "AVERAGE TRAVEL TIME"
FROM [Source].[dbo].[Source] RT1
WHERE
    RT1.[Segment_Date] >= @StartDateTime
    AND RT1.[Segment_Date] < @EndDateTime
GROUP BY
    (DATEPART(YEAR, RT1.[Segment_Date])),(DATEPART(MONTH, RT1.[Segment_Date])),(DATEPART(DD, RT1.[Segment_Date])),(DATEPART(HH, RT1.[Segment_Date]))
ORDER BY
    (DATEPART(YEAR, RT1.[Segment_Date])),(DATEPART(MONTH, RT1.[Segment_Date])),(DATEPART(DD, RT1.[Segment_Date])),(DATEPART(HH, RT1.[Segment_Date]))
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired rsults would help.

Comment: Also preparing a sqlfiddle is a plus

Comment: DB tagged and desired results added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the condition of the `CASE` expression to the `WHERE` clause.
Then group by `Code` also to get the averages of each `Code` and use `SUM()` window function to get the sum of all averages:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    DATEPART(YEAR, [Segment_Date]) AS [YEAR],
    DATEPART(MONTH, [Segment_Date]) AS [MONTH],
    DATEPART(DD, [Segment_Date]) AS [DAY],
    DATEPART(HH, [Segment_Date]) AS [HOUR],
    SUM(AVG([TravelTimeMinutes])) OVER (
      PARTITION BY DATEPART(YEAR, [Segment_Date]), 
                   DATEPART(MONTH, [Segment_Date]), 
                   DATEPART(DD, [Segment_Date]), 
                   DATEPART(HH, [Segment_Date])
      ) AS [AVERAGE TRAVEL TIME]
FROM [Source].[dbo].[Source] 
WHERE [Segment_Date] >= @StartDateTime
  AND [Segment_Date] < @EndDateTime
  AND [Code] IN ('149242059', '393397506', '393507671', '429235061', '429235101', '429235108', '429235159', '429235160', '429235161', '429255654', '429255655')
GROUP BY [Code], DATEPART(YEAR, [Segment_Date]), DATEPART(MONTH, [Segment_Date]), DATEPART(DD, [Segment_Date]), DATEPART(HH, [Segment_Date])
ORDER BY DATEPART(YEAR, [Segment_Date]), DATEPART(MONTH, [Segment_Date]), DATEPART(DD, [Segment_Date]), DATEPART(HH, [Segment_Date]);
```

Comment: thank but same issue, still getting the average of the times from each segment/code vs the combined average of all the segments/code

Comment: @user3096487 there is no `group by code` so I don't understand how you get average for each code. You should get the average for all codes.

Comment: it is returning the average of all codes (.41 for example) but I need the combined total average of all of the codes. (6.4 - made up number) .   example: code 1 = .5, code 2 = .7, code 3 = .6    result I am getting is .6 when I am looking for 1.8

Comment: @user3096487 by combined do you mean the sum of all averages for each code?

Comment: yes.  hopefully my last comment clarifies better

Comment: unfortunately same results.

Comment: @user3096487 take some time and post here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017 sample data and also post expected results for this sample data to clarify what you want.

Comment: how do I post there?  I have scripted data and desired results but don't see how to add and link to the questions

Comment: @user3096487 copy and paste the links here.

Comment: actually you edits worked.   I  had one of your edits missing last time.  Thank you